# ¿Cómo hacer una validación de login en php, javascript, css y html?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, postgresql

¿Cómo puedo hacer una validación de login?
La verdad soy algo nuevo en esto de la programación y necesito crear esta verificación de login para un proyecto escolar pero no encuentro ninguna forma de hacerlo y me quedo atascado a la hora de hacerlo.
Me ayudarían mucho si pudieran ayudarme, dejó a continuación el código del website y de la base de datos (está hecha en PostgreSQL).

```
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>VaidrollTeamLogin6</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="pagina de registro 2.css">   
</head>

<body>
<div class="cajafuera" align="center">
<div class="formulariocaja" align="center">
<form method="post" action="" name="vaidrollteam">
<div class="formtitulo">Registrate</div>

<div class="input-container">
    <input type="text" name="nombre" placeholder="Ingresar nombre:" class="cajaentradatexto">
    <input type="text" name="apellidos" placeholder="Ingresar apellidos:" class="cajaentradatexto">
</div>

<div class="input-container-2">
    <input type="text" name="Edad" placeholder="Edad:" class="cajaentradatexto">
    <input type="text" name="Peso" placeholder="Peso:" class="cajaentradatexto">  
    <input type="text" name="Estatura" placeholder="Estatura:" class="cajaentradatexto">
</div>

<div class="input-container-3">
    <input type="text" name="Edad" placeholder="Nombre de usuario" class="cajaentradatexto_nombre_de_usuario">
</div>
<div class="input-container">
    <input type="text" name="correo" placeholder="Ingresar correo:" class="cajaentradatexto_nombre_de_usuario">
</div>

<div class="input-container">
    <input type="password" name="contraseña" placeholder="Ingresar contraseña:" class="cajaentradatexto">
</div>

<div class="botondeprueba">
    <a type="submit" type="button" href="Loggin.html" >Registrarse</a> 
</div>

<div class="input-container_abajo">
     <input type="button" value="Registrarse con google" class="botonenviar_2" >
</div>

</form>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

La Base de Datos:

```
CREATE TABLE usuarios(
  ide SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  Nombre text NOT NULL,
  Apellidos text NOT NULL,
  Usuario varchar (20) NOT NULL,
  Correo text NOT NULL,
  Contraseña text NOT NULL,
  Sexo char,
  Edad integer NOT NULL,
  Peso double precision NOT NULL,
  Estatura double precision NOT NULL
  Imagen text
);
```

**ACTUALIZACIÓN**

He conseguido hacer la validación de formulario para el sitio web, lo he hecho en PHP como me recomendaron pero ahora tengo problemas al momento de intentar registrar usuarios a la base de datos.

```
<?php

require 'formulario.php';

session_start();

$usuario=$_POST['txtusuario'];
$clave=$_POST['txtpassword'];

$query=("SELECT*FROM usuarios WHERE 
Usuario='$usuario' AND Contraseña='$clave");

$consulta=pg_query($conexion,$query);
$cantidad=pg_num_rows($consulta);

if ($cantidad>0){

    $_SESSION['nombre_usuario']=$usuario;
    header('Location:ingreso.php');
}
else{
    echo "Datos Incorrectos";
}
```

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so], como habrás leído en el [tour] imagino que entiendes un poco como funciona el sitio. Te recomiendo que leas [ask] para que veas como una pregunta sea bienvenida. No parece que hayas intentado mucho para hacer el login, pero para ello puedes utilizar `PHP` por ejemplo. Haciendo que cuando le des a hacer login, envíe tu formulario y mediante sentencias `SQL` valides si el usuario realmente existe. Cuando hayas conseguido hacer esto, te recomendaría utilizar Hash-es, ya que enviar la contraseña directamente al servidor en plano no es nada seguro y es una mala práctica.

Comment: y cual es el error?

Comment: @ArcanisGK507 El error que tengo es hacer la alta de usuarios en mi página de registros, si bien ya tengo la validación de usuario en formato php conectado al sitio web, no consigo que el registro de usuarios conecte con mi base de datos para ingresar nuevos usuarios.

Comment: @Maida una disculpa, soy nuevo usuario y pensé que la pregunta era válida. Igualmente he intentado hacer la validación en php para conectar mi base de datos con el formulario de registros pero no sé como hacer que se puedan registrar usuarios desde el sitio web a la base de datos.

Comment: la necesidad de hacer algo no es un error... es flojera el no intentar hacerlo... en el sitio no hacemos tareas en la forma que presentas tu iniciativa ... simplemente ayudamos a quien esta trabado en un lugar especifico del codigo con un error...

Comment: La forma de hacer el registro de usuarios, funciona de forma similar a como hacer la validación, pero en vez de enviar una consulta a la BBDD y esperar que esta te responda, tendrás que utilizas `INSERT INTO usuarios` y los datos que necesites. Los datos los consigues de la misma forma que para hacer el login. Creas un formulario que el usuario rellene con los datos necesarios, y luego los envías al PHP. Una vez tienes ahí los datos simplemente tendrás que manejarlos como más te convenga